# Flink trigger on a custom window

Tags: apache-flink

I'm trying to evaluate Apache Flink for the use case we're currently running in production using custom code.

So let's say there's a stream of events each containing a specific attribute **X** which is a continuously increasing integer. That is a bunch of contiguous events have this attributes set to N, then the next batch has it set to N+1 etc.
I want to break the stream into windows of events with the same value of **X** and then do some computations on each separately.

So I define a GlobalWindow and a custom Trigger where in *onElement* method I check the attribute of any given element against the saved value of the current X (from state variable) and if they differ I conclude that we've accumulated all the events with X=CURRENT and it's time to do computation and increase the X value in the state.

The problem with this approach is that the element from the next logical batch (with X=CURRENT+1) has been already consumed but it's not a part of the previous batch.
Is there a way to put it back somehow into the stream so that it is properly accounted for the next batch?

Or maybe my approach is entirely wrong and there's an easier way to achieve what I need?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are on a right track.

`Trigger` specifies when a window can be processed and results for a window can be emitted.

The `WindowAssigner` is the part which says to which window element will be assigned. So I would say you also need to provide a custom implementation of `WindowAssigner` that will assign same window to all elements with equal value of X.

Answer (score 1):

A more idiomatic way to do this with Flink would be to use `stream.keyBy(X).window(...)`.  The `keyBy(X)` takes care of grouping elements by their particular value for X.  You then apply any sort of window you like.  In your case a SessionWindow may be a good choice.  It will fire for each key after that key hasn't been seen for some configurable period of time.

This approach will be much more robust with regard to unordered data which you must always assume in a stream processing system.

Comment: Thanks Jamie. The problem in my case is that there's no well-defined gap between different values of X. That is the only way I know that I've got all the values for X=N is that when I see X=N+1, so the gap can be a couple of days or even weeks.